# Const assertion with type requirements

Tags: typescript, types

In TypeScript, I have a class `Foo` and want to create a static array `bar` with const assertion where the values in the array are limited to the keys of Foo. The array is used as the type in `func` and also used as a runtime check.

Here's how I currently have it: ([more details in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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))

```
class Foo { a?: string; b?: string; c?: string }

const bar = ['a', 'b'] as const // need way for this to error if some 'd' which is not in Foo is added to the array

function func(arg: typeof bar[number]) { // TS should know arg is a keyof Foo as well
  // ...
  // some runtime usage of bar
}
```

I've also tried:

```
const bar: (keyof Foo)[] = ['a', 'b']
// but arg is now typed as any keyof Food, and accepts any key, not just 'a' and 'b'

const bar: (keyof Foo)[] = ['a', 'b'] as const
// throws an Error: The type 'readonly ["a", "b"]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type '(keyof Foo)[]
```

`Pick` gets an object version, so that doesn't work.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```js
class Foo { a?: string; b?: string; c?: string }

function getArgs<T extends ReadonlyArray<keyof Foo>>(args: T): T {
  return args
}

const bar1 = getArgs(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] as const) // error

function func1(arg: typeof bar1[number]) {
  // ...
  const f = new Foo()
  console.log('bar', bar1)
  console.log('f[arg]', f[arg])
}

const bar2 = getArgs(['a', 'b'] as const)

function func2(arg: typeof bar2[number]) {
  // ...
  const f = new Foo()
  console.log('bar', bar1)
  console.log('f[arg]', f[arg])
}

func2('c') // error
```

Comment: Added an edit to slightly cleanup types, but generally this works well! Accepted. Thanks!